# Настроить редирект сайта

Tags: php, .htaccess, редирект

Подскажите, как настроить редирект со страниц типа site.ru/ru/* на site.ru/* ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

На PHP: `site.ru/ru/` в `index.php`:

```
header("Location: site.ru/куда_перенаправить");
```

Стоит учитывать, что ДО этой записи не должно ничего выводиться

Через htaccess: [можно почитать тут](https://2domains.ru/support/hosting/htaccess-redirect#kak-nastroit-redirekt-cerez-htaccess) или погуглить

Comment: зачем запускать пхп если с этой задачей отлично справляется сам вэб-сервер?

Comment: @teran         затем же, зачем и задавать вопрос в вопросе. Можете предложить свое решение - пишите ответ. Посмотрите теги вопроса, исходя из них и дан ответ.